# Navigating native to forms in Xamarin gives null reference exception

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have 4 tabs in Xamarin.Android project(natively).
3 tabs are loaded natively,but one tab I am loading is a Forms page(content page).
Here is the codes for tabs-

```cs
    public override Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetItem(int position)
        {

            switch (position)
            {
                case 0:
                    return new tab1Fragment();

                case 1:
                    return new tab2Fragment();

                case 2:
                    return new tab3Fragment();                   

                case 3:
                   var fragment = new FormsPage1().CreateSupportFragment(Android.App.Application.Context);
                    return fragment;

                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
```

The forms page is loaded successfully,but when I touch anywhere in that page,it crashes.Here is the exception-

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Android.Views.View.n_DispatchTouchEvent_Landroid_view_MotionEvent_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_e)
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.55(intptr,intptr,intptr)
 Unhandled Exception from source=AndroidEnvironment
 System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PlatformRenderer.DispatchTouchEvent (Android.Views.MotionEvent e) 
at Android.Views.View.n_DispatchTouchEvent_Landroid_view_MotionEvent_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_e)
```

Updating the Xaml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ClientApp"
         x:Class="ClientApp.FormsPage1">

<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>
```

When I debugged more the view of the fragment always null,I am suspecting that this is causing the issue,
but not sure..Please help ..

Comment: First of all you are missing `break` statements in your code

Comment: @Prateek well, you only need them if you don't return... So that's inaccurate for a start...

Comment: @yes...if we use return ,there is not need of break

Comment: Do you have any code in your activity that overrides the Motion or Touch events? Please share that code

Comment: Also what’s your Xamarin forms version and are there any NuGet packages you personally added? Could you also share the C# Code behind of your Page? And whatS the Android target framework and target version ?

Comment: @saamer-No codes for touch in the activity..all other tabs are working perfectly..only the forms page is not working and code behind also have nothing just initializecomponent()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would expect this problem to appear because you are using the app's `Context` and not the activity `Context`. In most cases it is fine as a context provider, but sometimes it causes problems.

I am not sure of your project structure to recommend the best solution of how to get the activity context, but the CurrentActivity plugin should work in all cases.

Comment: Ok...I will check this one...and get back to you

Comment: Thanks a lot...i guess this was the problemm...we need to pass the current activity instead of context

Answer (score 2):

user   Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, null);  in your code before you create fragment

```
   if (__fragment1  == null)  
    {  

        // iOS  
        //Forms.Init()  
        //var iosViewController = new MyFormsPage().CreateViewController();  



        Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, null);  
        // #2 Use it  
        _fragment1 = new MainPage().CreateFragment(this);  
    }
```

Comment: I already did it...still view of that content page is coming null..thats why it is giving null reference exception when we touch view is null

Comment: these are the lines i added Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("FastRenderers_Experimental");
            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(Android.App.Application.Context, null);

Comment: can you update your xml view that will help to understand issue much better